# POST method to grails resource - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, grails, post, jax-rs

I would like to send some data with POST to my grails application.

I have got a really easy domain:

```
class Step {

    String name;
    Long taskId = -1;

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I implemented service for it:

```
@Path('/api/step')
class StepResource {


  @POST
  @Consumes(['application/json'])
  String create(Step dto) {
      // dto.save()
  }
}
```

I added plugin to Google Chrome to test it - POSTMAN and try to POST.

The result is:

[image]

The grails console prints:

```
| Error 2013-06-08 23:30:25,574 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR container.ContainerRequest  - A message body reader for Java class java.lang.Object, and Java type class java.lang.Object, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Could you give me any solution ?

Comment: Do you have `grails.mime.use.accept.header` set to `true` in `Config.groovy`?

Comment: I changed it to true but it is still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you should print it..
just declare the string
Also change the method type to String
Also go over the documentation. It's the easiest approach 
https://github.com/krasserm/grails-jaxrs/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Thank you, I did some changes in POST method (I updated my post). Now, I have got another error which is really strange, I quess is something wrong in data format I am sendning : **Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
/baza/api/step
Class
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message
Cannot cast object '9' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class 'java.util.Map'**